# How href="#" works?

Tags: html, href

https://www.rcsb.org/stats/growth/overall

On the above page, the link under "CSV" is shown as `https://www.rcsb.org/stats/growth/overall#`. When I click it, it will download a CSV file. Could anybody show me how the browser figure out the actual download URL? Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the event listeners in the developers console?

Comment: How to check the event listeners?

Comment: The question is not clear, because it has nothing to do with '#'.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening with an onclick event in one of these libraries. You'll have to dig through to find out which. I'm using firefox Developer edition. It does a great job showing what event triggers are attached to elements.

[image]

Here's some additional info about the library DataTables JS which looks like what this is using: https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html

Example:
'''http://example.com/link/to/file.csv;">Download file!'''

Comment: If I want to scrape that CSV file, what is the easiest way to capture the URL. Postman seems not able to capture anything about the URL of the CSV file.

Comment: It seems that FF dev ed is better than chrome in showing events. Is it so?

Comment: @user1424739 I think so. I've tried Chrome Canary for dev tools, but it still doesn't seem as beneficial as FF Dev.